# Find and modify JSF component in backing bean

Tags: jsf, controller, components

I have a `<h:outputText>` in the view.
In the controller, I would like to use below code to manipulate the `value` and `style` attributes. Is it possible?

```
private void updateMsgCreateRegistrationKey(String objectName, String msg, String msgType){
    UIComponent UIOutputText = getUIComponentOfId(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot(), objectName);
    if (UIOutputText != null){
        UIOutputText.setRendered(true);
        if(msgType.equalsIgnoreCase("Info")){

        }else if(msgType.equalsIgnoreCase("Error")){

        }
    }
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(objectName);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
}
```

Comment: _"Is it possible??"_: **try it...**

Comment: Probably it is, but why.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the normal approach. You normally don't manipulate the view from the controller on. Instead, in MVC, you let the controller (the backing bean) manipulate the model (the backing bean properties) and let the view (the XHTML file) check the model (the backing bean properties).

```
private String value;
private String styleClass;
private boolean rendered;

public void someMethod() {
    value = "some value";
    styleClass = "someClass";
    rendered = true;
}

// +getters (no setters necessary)
```

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.value}"
              styleClass="#{bean.styleClass}"
              rendered="#{bean.rendered}" />
```

Or even without `rendered` property:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.value}"
              styleClass="#{bean.styleClass}"
              rendered="#{not empty bean.value}" />
```

Every time you thought you need to grab an `UIComponent` from the view in the controller, stop immediately and think twice if you're really doing things the right way.

#### See also:

- [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used)